# Boto3 Script to List EBS Snapshots Older than 30 days while exporting instance data to CSV

Tags: python-3.x, amazon-ec2, boto3, snapshot, amazon-ebs

Looking for a boto3 script to identify EBS snapshots older than 30 days that identifies Instance ID, Volume ID, Volume Name, Volume Size, and Volume Type, and then have that data export to a CSV.

Our plan is to ultimately delete the snapshots older than 30 days but are looking to just start with identification.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to get that information.

For an explanation of the fields accessed, see [`describe_snapshots()`](https://boto3.amazonaws.com/v1/documentation/api/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#EC2.Client.describe_snapshots). That documentation also shows sample output, which makes it relatively easy to code this type of script.

```py
import boto3
from datetime import datetime, timezone

ec2_client = boto3.client('ec2')

snapshot_response = ec2_client.describe_snapshots(OwnerIds=['self'])

for snapshot in snapshot_response['Snapshots']:
    print(snapshot['SnapshotId'])
    print(snapshot['VolumeId'])
    print(snapshot['VolumeSize'])
    print(snapshot['StartTime'])
    days_old = (datetime.now(timezone.utc) - snapshot['StartTime']).days
    print(days_old)

    volume_response = ec2_client.describe_volumes(VolumeIds=[snapshot['VolumeId']])
    volume = volume_response['Volumes'][0]
    print(volume['VolumeType'])
    for attachment in volume['Attachments']:
        print(attachment['InstanceId'])
```

The call to `describe_volumes()` was required to retrieve the `VolumeType` and `InstanceId` because they are attributes of the volume from which the Snapshot was produced. If you are merely deleting snapshots based on their creation date, you should not need to call `describe_volumes()`.

Comment: Thank you so much for taking the time to do this John

Comment: What would the deletion bit look like? And, do we not need to import CSV at the beginning as well?  Apologies for the lack of knowledge, I'm just starting out and am looking to get some advice/headway on a project I've been assigned.

Comment: The deletion code would simply have an `if` statement based on `days_old`, then call `ec2_client.terminate_instances()` with the Instance ID. To learn how to create CSV files, just do a web search for `python write CSV`.